Nginx: 404 код, файл не найден
В блоке server, выставлено правило
error_page 404 =404 /index.php?do=404;

Оно работает в том случае, если ссылка не ведет на файл.
Если ссылка ведет на файл, то отдает код 404 со стандартной страницей браузер.
Собственно, вопрос в том, как заставить данное правило работать, в том числе, если файл не найден?
server {
    server_name site.ru www.site.ru;
    root /var/www/site.ru;
    index index.php;

    ##################################################################
    #### Перенаправляем с wwww на без
    ##################################################################
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)$) {
        return 301 https://site.ru$request_uri;
    }

    error_page 404 =404 /index.php?do=404;
    location / {

        location ~* ^/faq-(offer)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?do=u&po=$1&$args;  
        }

    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    location /pma {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;

        }
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
Добавлено:
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|webp)$ {
   
}

Как верно прописать, если URL ведет на файл и его нет на сервере, отдать URL другой страницы?

Приведите полный конфиг, в том числе часть, отвечающую за отдачу файлов

Добавил........

Что-то не очень понятно как с таким конфигом может вылезти «стандартная» страница, приведите примеры «работающих» и «неработающих» ссылок?

Добавил к вопросу. Как в целом определить что обращение к файлу не к конкретному расширению?
